# understanding javascript syntax with .value

Tags: javascript

I have a text box which automatically changes the value entered by the user to uppercase, the code works just the way I want it to:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

However, if I re-write it as follows, it does not change the text box value to uppercase :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value; <--- notice I added value here
    x = x.toUpperCase();
}
```

My impression was that both excerpts would serve the same purpose, so why is it that the second one does not work the way I intend it to?

Comment: What do you mean by `does not compile`. Do you get an error, or it just doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: sorry ill re-edit. It doesn't change the user-entered value of the text box to uppercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first snippet, `x` is a DOM Element whose `value` attribute you change by assigning

```
x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
```

In the second snippet, `x` is just a *plain `String`* which holds no reference to the DOM element.
It's same as doing `"someString" = "someOtherString"` and obviously, it won't be reflected in the DOM, as there is no reference to the DOM element anywhere.

Summary:

- In first snippet you're using `setter`, so the `value` gets uptated.
- In second snippet you're using `getter` and changing the *returned* value of it, which doens't reflect in the DOM element.

Comment: @self: If by "pass by reference" you mean "a reference to the object is passed" then yes. Usually, "pass by reference" means that a reference to the variable is passed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference